# Show small image to full screen width using css .

Tags: css

I have following css :

```
.image{
background: url('image.png') no-repeat;
width:100%
}
```

My image size is small and I want this image to be stretched in full screen with repeating it .Please help me on this .

Thanks.

Comment: with repeating it or *without* repeating it?

Comment: without repeating it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size: cover;` ... but bear in mind that if it is a small image - then by stretching it the quality of the resulting background may be poor.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8PW2V/)**

### CSS

```
div {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food') no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
```